# Binary classification in TensorFlow, unexpected large values for loss and accuracy

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am trying to use a deep neural network architecture to classify against a binary label value - -1 and +1. Here is my code to do it in `tensorflow`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from preprocess import create_feature_sets_and_labels

train_x,train_y,test_x,test_y = create_feature_sets_and_labels()

x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 5])
y = tf.placeholder('float')

n_nodes_hl1 = 500
n_nodes_hl2 = 500
n_nodes_hl3 = 500

n_classes = 1
batch_size = 100

def neural_network_model(data):

    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, n_nodes_hl1])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl1, n_nodes_hl2])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl2, n_nodes_hl3])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                      'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}


    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data, hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1, hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2, hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases']))
    return output



def train_neural_network(x):
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0
            i = 0
            while i < len(train_x):
                start = i
                end = i + batch_size
                batch_x = np.array(train_x[start:end])
                batch_y = np.array(train_y[start:end])

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                              y: batch_y})
                epoch_loss += c
                i+=batch_size

            print('Epoch', epoch, 'completed out of', hm_epochs, 'loss:', epoch_loss)

        # correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        # accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, 'float'))

        print (test_x.shape)
        accuracy = tf.nn.l2_loss(prediction-y,name="squared_error_test_cost")/test_x.shape[0]
        print('Accuracy:', accuracy.eval({x: test_x, y: test_y}))

train_neural_network(x)
```

This is the output I get when I run this:

```
('Epoch', 0, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -8400.2424869537354)
('Epoch', 1, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -78980.956665039062)
('Epoch', 2, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -152401.86713409424)
('Epoch', 3, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -184913.46441650391)
('Epoch', 4, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -165563.44775390625)
('Epoch', 5, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -360394.44857788086)
('Epoch', 6, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -475697.51550292969)
('Epoch', 7, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -588638.92993164062)
('Epoch', 8, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -745006.15966796875)
('Epoch', 9, 'completed out of', 10, 'loss:', -900172.41955566406)
(805, 5)
('Accuracy:', 5.8077128e+09)
```

I don't understand if the values I am getting are correct as there is a real dearth of non-MNIST binary classification examples. The accuracy is nothing like what I expected. I was expecting a percentage instead of that large value.

I am also somewhat unsure of the theory behind machine learning which is why I can't tell the correctness of my approach using tensorflow.

Can someone please tell me if my approach towards binary classification is correct?
Also is the accuracy part of my code correct?

Comment: It seems like your network is unstable. Try performing the computation with lesser layers, or using xavier-glorot initialization?

Comment: I think your indentation is not right for the Python in the question. Could you fix it please to be same as your original code (I think I see what the code is you tried to paste, but debugging Python is made a lot harder if you don't copy the indentation correctly)?

Comment: @NeilSlater fixed indentation.

Comment: @KalpeshKrishna I reduced it to two layers. My accuracy is 9433441.0. How do I use xavier-glorot initialization in my code? Most examples include explicity setting up weights.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From this:

> a binary label value - -1 and +1

. . . I am assuming your values in `train_y` and `test_y` are actually -1.0 and +1.0

This is not going to work very well with your chosen loss function `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` - which assumes 0.0 and +1.0. The negative `y` values are causing mayhem! However, the loss function choice is good for binary classification. I suggest change your `y` values to 0 and 1.

In addition, technically the output of your network is not the final prediction. The loss function `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` is designed to work with a network with sigmoid transfer function in the output layer, although you have got it right that the loss function is applied *before* this is done. So your training code appears correct

I'm not 100% sure about the `tf.transpose` though - I would see what happens if you remove that, personally I.e.

```
output = tf.add(tf.matmul(l3, output_layer['weights']), output_layer['biases'])
```

Either way, this is the "logit" output, but not your prediction. The value of `output` can get high for very confident predictions, which probably explains your very high values later due to missing the sigmoid function. So add a prediction tensor (this represents the probability/confidence that the example is in the positive class):

```
prediction = tf.sigmoid(output)
```

You can use that to calculate accuracy. Your accuracy calculation should not be based on L2 error, but sum of correct values - closer to the code you had commented out (which appears to be from a multiclass classification). For a comparison with true/false for binary classification, you need to threshold the predictions, and compare with the true labels. Something like this:

```
 predicted_class = tf.greater(prediction,0.5)
 correct = tf.equal(predicted_class, tf.equal(y,1.0))
 accuracy = tf.reduce_mean( tf.cast(correct, 'float') )
```

The accuracy value should be between 0.0 and 1.0. If you want as a percentage, just multiply by 100 of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil! However, there are still some issues. Updating question with details.

Comment: @VineetKaushik: Please *don't* change your question if it makes it different. For instance don't add my suggested fix and ask why it is now not working. Because that invalidates my answer - i.e. all my work, and the benefit to anyone else with same problem

Comment: @VineetKaushik: If my answer helped you get past the problem with large incorrect values when training and testing, then please instead ask a new question with the new problem.

Comment: Damn. Ok. Moving it to a new question.

Comment: @VineetKaushik: Thanks. It is better this way, to have each problem separate and not one long conversation. You can always *link* this question in your next one, so someone can follow the whole discussion if they like.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Neil. Here is the new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709870/loss-not-reducing-in-binary-classification-using-tensorflow