# TensorFlow - Simple Feed Forward NN not training

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm new to TensorFlow and just constructed my first very small network!!  My code runs, but it has the same accuracy all along; it doesn't change with training. My data has 15 features and 6 classes. Maybe I'll add more features if that makes it easier and better. In short, my question is:

## What's a general procedure for debugging TensorFlow code?

My network architecture was determined arbitrarily, so maybe I should change the number of neurons per layer, not entirely sure.

```
sess1 = tf.Session()

num_predictors = len(training_predictors_tf.columns)
num_classes = len(training_classes_tf.columns)

feature_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_predictors])
actual_classes = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes])

weights1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_predictors, 50], stddev=0.0001))
biases1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([50]))

weights2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([50, 45], stddev=0.0001))
biases2 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([45]))
                     
weights3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([45, 25], stddev=0.0001))
biases3 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([25]))

weights4 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, num_classes], stddev=0.0001))
biases4 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([num_classes]))

hidden_layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(feature_data, weights1) + biases1)
hidden_layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_1, weights2) + biases2)
hidden_layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(hidden_layer_2, weights3) + biases3)

out = tf.matmul(hidden_layer_3, weights4) + biases4

model = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=actual_classes, logits=out)

# cost = -tf.reduce_sum(actual_classes*tf.log(model))


cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean( model)

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05).minimize(cross_entropy)


# train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0001).minimize(cross_entropy)

sess1.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(out, 1), tf.argmax(actual_classes, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

for i in range(1, 30001):
    sess1.run(
        train_step, 
        feed_dict={
            feature_data: training_predictors_tf.values, 
            actual_classes: training_classes_tf.values.reshape(len(training_classes_tf.values), num_classes)
        }
    )
    if i%5000 == 0:
        print(i, sess1.run(
            accuracy,
            feed_dict={
                feature_data: training_predictors_tf.values, 
                actual_classes: training_classes_tf.values.reshape(len(training_classes_tf.values), num_classes)
            }
        ))
```

And this is my output:

```
5000 0.3627
10000 0.3627
15000 0.3627
20000 0.3627
25000 0.3627
30000 0.3627
```

EDIT: I scaled my data as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709870/changing-accuracy-value-and-no-change-in-loss-value-in-binary-classification-usi), in the range of [-5;0] but it still does not train the network any better :(

Snippet of unscaled data (one-hot encoding first 6 columns):

```
2017-06-27  0   0   0   1   0   0   20120.0 20080.0 20070.0 20090.0 ... 20050.0 20160.0 20130.0 20160.0 20040.0 20040.0 20040.0 31753.0 36927.0 41516.0
2017-06-28  0   0   1   0   0   0   20150.0 20120.0 20080.0 20150.0 ... 20060.0 20220.0 20160.0 20130.0 20130.0 20040.0 20040.0 39635.0 31753.0 36927.0
2017-06-29  0   0   0   1   0   0   20140.0 20150.0 20120.0 20140.0 ... 20090.0 20220.0 20220.0 20160.0 20100.0 20130.0 20040.0 50438.0 39635.0 31753.0
2017-06-30  0   1   0   0   0   0   20210.0 20140.0 20150.0 20130.0 ... 20150.0 20270.0 20220.0 20220.0 20050.0 20100.0 20130.0 58983.0 50438.0 39635.0
2017-07-03  0   0   0   1   0   0   20020.0 20210.0 20140.0 20210.0 ... 20140.0 20250.0 20270.0 20220.0 19850.0 20050.0 20100.0 88140.0 58983.0 50438.0
```

Comment: Anything helps! :)

Comment: Do you mean you scale to [-5; 5] ? It's probably not that, but you should probably use a bigger stddev for weights (0.1 typically), and maybe use random bias initialization as well (but centered around a positive value, 0.1 for instance). Even cleverer initializations exist, but that would already make sure that this is not the problem.

Comment: Wow, you're right! Changing the stddev for the weights was able to improve the outcome sligthly, but at least we are getting an output other than giving me the same accuracy and probability regardless of the input. Thanks!

Comment: When I run your code with the smaller data you've provided (with rescaling) it works perfectly, so there is no direct code problem (except maybe with the way you input your data), so it has to be a runtime problem that you get for big data and not for small data. Exploding gradient is a perfect candidate. Have you tried with a smaller learning rate ? Have you checked all interesting tensors for infinity/Nan values ? Have you tried gradient clipping ?

Comment: Without rescaling of course the loss stays almost constant, due to the LR being way too low w.r.t. the input values involved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging your network and improving it are two different things. To improve it, once you've chosen a type of classifier (for instance a neural network), you should use the training and validation accuracies, and adjust your hyperparameters in functions of both of these. See the chapter [Practical methodology of Goodfellow and alii's book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/guidelines.html) for instance to know how to tune the hyperparameters (it's a bit long, but pure gold !).

As to debugging, this is the harder part. You usually do that by printing some "key tensor" values every once in a while. You clearly have a bug somewhere, or your accuracy would change at least a bit during training. A common problem causing that is exploding gradient, that causes `Nan`s to appear very early in training (sometimes infinity or even 0s at strange places), which then basically stops any update in your network. I'd suggest printing your loss, and maybe the norm of your gradients, that should tell you if this is the problem. If so, the quick-and-dirty solution is to use a smaller LR at start and then augment it. The real solution is to use gradient clipping.

Example of how to print multiple tensor values:

```
if i%5000 == 0:
    acc_val, loss_val, predictions = sess1.run(
        [accuracy, cross_entropy, tf.argmax(out, 1)],
        feed_dict={
            feature_data: training_predictors_tf.values, 
            actual_classes: training_classes_tf.values.reshape(len(training_classes_tf.values), num_classes)
        })
    print(i, acc_val, loss_val) # You can also print predictions, but it will be very big so it'll be harder to see the others. Doing it would allow you to check if, for instance, the model always predicts class 0...
```

Comment: Thank you for the book link! Will take a look at it shortly.

Now, about the debugging, where would you print the gradients and loss, and how? I know there's something about Tensors not being accessible at points, as it prints that it is a Tensor as opposed to the actual value.

Let me know if you spot the bug! I've triple checked my code but to no avail :'(

Comment: I've edited my post to show you how to print the values in a tensor for debugging. Other interesting nodes to show could be `out` (to see if it contains some `Nan`s or not), maybe the gradients norm, `feature_data` and `actual_classes` to check that your data is passed correctly in the network...

Comment: Thanks, gdelab! Yea, as expected, the loss_val remains constant throughout training. Also, check my update for a snippet of the data.

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of the other tensors I've suggested ? You can also try printing the weights, to see if they change at all. There has to be something weird somewhere in the tensor values (too many 0s, Nans, or infinity), and good candidates for that are loss, gradient, logits (out), and then the others.

Comment: When I run your code with the smaller data you've provided (with rescaling) it works perfectly, so there is no direct code problem (except maybe with the way you input your data), so it has to be a runtime problem that you get for big data and not for small data. Exploding gradient is a perfect candidate. Have you tried with a smaller learning rate ? Have you checked all interesting tensors for infinity/Nan values ? Have you tried gradient clipping ?