# how to convert output of a single neuron to class of 0 and 1 in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, data-science

I have made a NN on titanic dataset. To compute accuracy of model I want the output Z3/A3 to be 1 if it is above 0.5 and 0 otherwise.

And if there is any other way to do this kind of thing. Then please tell.

Here is my forward prop function

```
def forward_prop(X, parameters):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    b2 = parameters['b2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']
    b3 = parameters['b3']

    Z1 = tf.matmul(W1, tf.transpose(X))
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(Z1, b1))
    Z2 = tf.matmul(W2, A1)
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(Z2, b2))
    Z3 = tf.matmul(W3, A2)
    A3 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(Z3, b3))

    return A3
```

The shape of output of A3 is (1,1)

Here's cost function

```
def compute_cost(Z3, Y, m):
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        labels=tf.transpose(Y), logits=Z3))
    return cost
```

It is giving outputs as some numbers... I want the output as discrete classes i.e 0 and 1.

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2):

[tf.nn.softmax()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax) computes probability distribution over classes (output neurons), if you have just 1 output neuron then probability distribution over 1 neuron will always be 1.0. I would suggest to use [tf.sigmoid()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sigmoid) in combination with [tf.greater()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/greater), e.g:

```
A3 = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(Z3, b3))
# ...
prediction = tf.greater(A3, 0.5)
```

*prediction* will return *True* if A3 is greater than 0.5, *False* otherwise.
You can convert boolean *prediction* to other types such as integers:

```
class_label = tf.cast(prediction, tf.int32)
```

This way True will be converted to 1 and False to 0.
As for cost function, use [tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits):

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.transpose(Y), logits=Z3))
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40709398/9535747) has more details about single neuron binary classification, I would further suggest you look into it.

Comment: LOL it's 3am and I'm forgetting my concepts. I knew I'm forgetting something and it came out to be sigmoid. And I didn't knew about tf.greater... Thank you so much :)

Comment: @MohitSaini your code may contain a bug, I updated the answer, please look at *** section

Comment: Here's my first model: https://codeshare.io/5wDbAp.  Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: @MohitSaini I looked at the code, that was not a bug, sorry about that. Otherwise looks ok, I didn't run the code though.